# Archiving automatically says it is complete even though it did not create an archive (Maui in VS22)

Tags: xamarin, maui

Trying to create an archive to make a release apk of my app, and whenever I click archive all, it instantly says the archive is completed, nothing shows in the archive manager, and there are no errors or absolutely anything for that matter shown for output.

I suspect it may have something to do with the versions as I was able to archive previously, but once I changed versions, I believe that is when the issue started. Also, the app builds and runs with no issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think the tooling for publishing and archiving is still work in progress. I'm not 100% up to date with the status though. However, if you run into these things please report it through the Visual Studio Help menu and choose Provide Feedback > Report a Problem.

That will make sure it goes to the right team with all the right information attached.

As a solution for you right now, the command-line does work. Everything needed to create a version is described in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/overview

Answer (score 1):

I have come across the same issue I think I may have identified the what may be causing the problem:

I did the following:

1. Created a new .NET MAUI App with .NET 7.0 (Standard Term Support). Without
   changing anything - I selected Archive All - this worked fine.

Changed the following project property:

Changed from:

[image]

Comment: Can confirm this is one of the things I changed, and one of the things I left alone when I reset to get it working again. Does changing it back allow you to archive again?

Comment: I am unable to reset the two properties back to blank in the editor. When trying to edit the project file, the above values for the TargetFramework are not there:      SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
  <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">32.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>]